# Location of OneNote notebooks (not-synced)

Tags: backup, sync, onedrive, microsoft-onenote, file-recovery

I have four notebooks on OneDrive that I use with OneNote 2016.

**I disabled automatic syncing.**

When I encountered an error and couldn't boot W10, I created a backup of the entire drive and chose to reset the PC with the option `Keep my files`. After the reset, I reinstalled Office, but found that the newly installed OneNote 2016 only showed the default `Quick Notes` notebook. I connected my Microsoft Account, and OneNote synced with OneDrive with the result that OneNote shows the version of the notebooks stored on OneDrive – and not the up-to-date versions on the PC before the reset.

**How do I retrieve the notebooks?**

I don't know where OneNote stores the notebooks that are not yet synced. Keep in my mind that I also have the drive backup if helpful.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/923700/where-is-the-offline-copy-of-my-onedrive-synced-onenote-file?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneNote stores the notebooks that are connected with OneDrive offline in the folders "cache" and "ServerListings" from `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote\<ver>`, but resetting W10 wipes the `C:\Users\<user>\AppData` folder.

To restore the notebooks, replace those current folders with the equivalent folders from the backup.

**NOTE:** For others who didn't do a backup, you might be able to restore the notebooks from `C:\Windows.old`.